# What kind of sentence structure is , "Would that be, If i were a rich man ! "

Tags: grammar, sentence-construction, sentence-structure, subjects, secondary-predicates

What kind of sentence structure is , "Would that be, If **I were** a rich man ! "

Isn't it incorrect English?

What kind of sentence is it, that is deemed valid to begin with, **Would that be**

AND

why not put **I was** instead of **I were**.

Comment: It **could** be valid English in the right context, but I think it more likely to be mistaken or mistranscribed. What's the context? Where did you find it? Are you sure it isn't *Would that I were a rich man?*

Comment: I'm thinking that you might have meant "That would be if I was a rich man"

Answer (score 1):

"If I were", historically, has been considered the *correct* phrasing; "if I was" is sometimes regarded as an error when used with the subjunctive mood.  See [this English Language and Usage answer](https://english.stackexchange.com/a/429514/) for *lots* more details.

"Would that be [...]!", on the other hand, is very unusual.  With a question mark instead of an exclamation mark, it would merely be archaic, and the whole thing would mean something along the lines of "is that really what would happen, if I were  a rich man?".  As written, however, I'm inclined to agree with StoneyB's comment: it looks like a sentence fragment, rather than a full sentence, which could be a stylistic choice, a mistake, or a transcription error.